# Why is it useful to use the method eval() with a string in python?

Tags: python

Why is it useful to use the method eval() with a string in python?

For example I have seen using it like that:

```
if color not in 'BGR':
   cv2method = eval(f'cv2.COLOR_BGR2{color}')
```

Comment: It's not terribly useful in the example and could be done is a safer manner without using it.

Comment: Your question is based on an opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty poor example of it. They're really spelling out this in a riskier manner:

```
cv2method = getattr(cv2, 'COLOR_BGR2'+color)
```

`eval` evaluates an arbitrary Python expression, and can thus cause all sorts of side effects. For instance, it could import new modules, run system commands, alter program state, and so on. It is useful precisely when you can trust the input and want to evaluate functions of other variables in it. Using its `globals` and `locals` arguments you could restrict it to a less risky environment.